# How to convert UTC time pulled from an API into local time using Python?

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

I currently have a field I'm pulling from an API called "categorized-at" that has this format:

```
"23/7/2020"
```

However, this API uses UTC+0000 time, but we need this to be in -0600 time. We submitted a ticket to the place that hosts the API asking for help and they were unable to assist us. However, I've made good process and have this chunk of code:

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone, timedelta
import time
from dateutil import tz

from_zone = tz.tzutc()
to_zone = tz.tzlocal()
utc = datetime.strptime('23/7/2020', '%d/%m/%Y')
utc = utc.replace(tzinfo=from_zone)
central = utc.astimezone(to_zone)
```

This works perfectly, but only if I include a specific date in the parameter of datetime.strptime - however, this needs to be applied to the "categorized_at" field for a report with thousands of values that needs to be automated. I tried to just include "categorized_at" in there like this:

```
utc = datetime.strptime('categorized_at', '%d/%m/%Y')
```

but no matter how I try and adjust the date formatting, I get the error

`'time data "categorized at' does not match '%d/%m/%Y'`

I feel like the solution here is something simple I'm overlooking, and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: so what is `categorized_at`? a list? a dict? `datetime.strptime` will only parse scalar values, so you might have to call it in a loop, e.g. `[datetime.strptime(element, '%d/%m/%Y') for element in categorized_at]`

Comment: @MrFuppes thank you for the response! i believe categorized_at stores dates as a string. categorized_at itself is just a collection of dates that are pulled from a server and formatted

Comment: ok so if it is a variable that holds a string that represents one date, it's just `datetime.strptime(categorized_at, '%d/%m/%Y')`, if there's multiple dates in the string, you'll need additional string parsing before conversion to datetime.

Comment: @MrFuppes i believe that might be my issue, and i apologize for not making it clear enough, 'categorized_at' is the name of a field that contains a collection of dates pulled from a server and formatted